# Ionic2 same header for all pages

Tags: ionic2

I would like to have the same header for all pages.

Whats the best way to do it without having to repeat the html + code in all pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an easier way, with no need to repeat code at all!
although it is not so straightforward it covered my needs:

Just place the `ion-header` component inside the `app` component together with the `ion-nav` component.

Change your app component template to this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-title>{{appTitle}}</ion-title>
</ion-header>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

and in your `app.scss` add some styling to make the page appear under the header:

```
.ion-page > ion-content
{
   top: 52px;//your headers height
}
```

This should show your header in all pages.

**Notice that this isn't recommended:**

> Having a different header for each page is a design decision we've made.
>   In Ionic 1, a common issue was that having a single header/navbar wasn't flexible enough for people.

Taken from [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/same-header-for-all-pages/75736/2)

Comment: what about signin page ?

Comment: I followed this but the problem is in iOS. iOS hotspot connection bar overlaps the header. 
Did you face this problem? How did you solve this?

Comment: You said "Notice that this isn't recommended". Any reasons why one shouldn't do that?

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by making header-component with configuration and then change configuration on different components accordingly.
Create custom header component.
 Lets Call it '**custom-header-component**' 
**custom-header-component.html**

```
<ion-navbar>
  <button *ngIf="header_data.ismenu" ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="header_data.ishome" class="algo-header-home-icon" ion-button icon-only (click)="homeClick()">
    <ion-icon class="ion-home" name="home"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title class="header-title" [ngClass]="{'ishome-title': header_data.ishome,'ismeun-centre': !header_data.ishome}">
    {{header_data.title}}
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

**custom-header-component.ts**

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-header',
  templateUrl: 'custom-header.html'
})
export class CustomHeaderComponent {
  header_data: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  @Input()
  set header(header_data: any) {
    this.header_data=header_data;
  }
  get header() {
    return this.header_data;
  }
  homeClick() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
}
```

This custom-header-component takes configurations '**ismenu**' of type boolean, '**ishome**' of type boolean and '**title**' of type string. Now lets use this component in page component '**home**'. We want home page component to only have title and ismenu. Our code looks like this.
**'home.html'**

```
<ion-header><custom-header [header]="header_data"></custom-header></ion-header>
 <ion-content padding class="page-home">
   <p>Home Page</p>
 </ion-content>
```

**'home.ts'**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  header_data:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.header_data={ismenu:true,ishome:false,title:"Home"};
  }
}
```

The home page header would look like this:

[image]

Comment: I've been round and round with this one before asking. All I get out of this is "Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-header' any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had to update the @Input to   @Input('header') header_data;

Also make sure to add the component to either app.module or your page module if you are lazy loading.

I used the above with some help from this link: https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question and couldn't find a proper way to do it.
I think the easiest way is to create a new component for your header and then include it in every page (referenced by its template).

I know you have to repeat the html-tag in every page, but it is only one line and also straight forward to read.

Comment: from docs "It's important to note that ion-header needs to be the one of the three root elements of a page" - this way the ion-header is not a direct child of page.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/2.0.1/api/components/toolbar/Header/ The other 2 are??